# How would I keep this text in the middle of the button?

Tags: html, css

Right now I have it so there's text in the middle of this button, and when you hover over it the height and width of the button change, but when you hover the text moves slightly to the top left. I'm curious as to how I would make it stay in the center when I hover over it. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```css
.center{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:blue;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top:auto;
  margin-bottom:auto;
  position:absolute;
  border:3px solid black;
  border-radius:15px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  float:left;
}

.center h1{
  color:Red;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1.5px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
  font-size:32px;
  position:absolute;
  padding-left:3px;
  padding-top:5px;
}

.center:hover{
  border:5px solid black;
  height:115px;
  width:115px;
}
```

```html
 <a href="Google.com">  <div class="center"> 
      <h1>
         Google
      </h1>
    </div>
    </a>
```

Comment: actually when I hover the background or border, the text will also move too, not sure if it just me or so... :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are lots of different approaches to centering content, and I probably wouldn't choose the approach that you have so far, but, if you want to stick with it, just adjust the padding of the `<h1>` appropriately:

```
.center:hover h1 {
    /* new padding here */
}
```